# Changing a vote to neutral toggle (Interface issue)

Tags: discussion, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Undo Vote Arrows UX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75402/undo-vote-arrows-ux)

I have a problem with the toggle settings on voting up/down/neutral.

Wouldn't it make more sense that clicking **UP**, after clicking **DOWN** would bring the vote to neutral, rather than the current way of clicking **DOWN** after clicking **DOWN** bringing it to neutral.

It makes it feel like a -2 vote and it really isn't intuitive. I only just figured out it was possible!

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate - that's my feature request. Funnily enough this has a duplicate suggestion too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad idea but what if it worked both ways? That way it would work "as expected" for everyone regardless of how you used it.

Comment: Good point, makes perfect sense!

Comment: +1 Exactly what has been suggested on the duplicate - great minds think alike :)

Comment: @chibacity ha sorry I didn't see that before. Thanks for the link. Lets hope this gets fixed!

Comment: @danixd No worries - I hope it gets fixed too. I one of those people who just don't "get it" :) OOI Are you left-handed?

Comment: Nope, I am right handed.

Comment: @danixd <strike>theory #9,999</strike> :)

Comment: @chibacity ha sorry to dissapoint! :)