# Why can't I revert vote back?

Tags: support, voting

On this question (the question is irrelevent, I'm just stating when I noticed this and where it happened) [Convert String to Enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213409/convert-string-to-enum)  I accidently upvoted an answer that I thought didn't deserve an upvote. The score of the answer was at the time 0.

After I upvoted, the answer went to +1. Obviously. I then realized my mistake, and downvoted the question because I wanted to take back my upvote.

The question's score went from +1 to -1 (a total of 2 points!) And I did not believe that the question deserved -1. Is this a bug? Shouldn't you be able to subtract from +1 to go back to 0?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75402/undo-vote-arrows-ux

Comment: Note the arrow tooltips say `(click again to undo)`, so this behavior *is* discoverable if you're patient enough to wait for the tooltip to appear :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Very true :) but patient is the last thing I am at this time of day

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: If you're patient, the vote will be locked and you won't be able to change it even if it's inaccurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on your upvote a second time, it should revert it.  Clicking on the downvote changes your upvote into a downvote.

Comment: Aha thank you :) I should have thought of this

Answer (score 2):

Just click on the colored arrow that reflects your vote. That will remove it.
If you upvoted by accident for example, click upvote again.